# Why is digitalRead/digitalWrite not working in C++ nor in gpio terminal commands?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, c++, wiringpi

I'm writing in C++ using WiringPi to integrate with GPIO but it doesn't seem to work during runtime.

Below I have a simple example of an output wired to an input expecting the input to read HIGH, but it is not outputting anything. I've tried running in the terminal `gpio -g mode 24 out` and neither the `Mode` or `V` voltage values change when running `gpio readall`.

```
wiringPiSetup();
pinMode(24, OUTPUT);
pinMode(25, INPUT);

while(true) 
{
digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
delay(500);
RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "25: %d", digitalRead(25)); // ROS 2 cout equivalent 
}
```

I've also tried configuring input reading from the 3.3V output and still reading 0. I used a voltmeter to confirm it wasn't a hardware issue.

Why is it not working? Any insight on how to fix/debug this?

#### Resources

- https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi *I know on the GitHub repo the WiringPi library will no longer be supported but I'm assuming it should still be working.*

Comment: Which OS??? Perhaps you didn't read enough?

Comment: Wiring Pi will not work on a Raspberry Pi 5. It's a wonder it still works anywhere, it's been unsupported since 2019. Change to any other GPIO library, like `gpiod`.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Model: Raspberry Pi 4

Comment: I actually got the gpio terminal commands working and it reflected correctly in the `gpio readall`. Using the library in a C++ file is not working still.

Comment: I was following [Setup](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/c-wiringpi-setup) and [API](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/c-wiringpi-api) and nothing on the second link worked for me.